# Append class to Shopify navigation menu item

Tags: html, css, navigation, shopify, liquid

I am customizing my theme's header. I want to have a centered logo, with three links on the left and right side. I figured that it is best to do this by putting an additional menu item in the center that will serve as my navigation logo image. I just need to append a custom class to this menu item, so that I can edit the CSS for this specific menu item. How can I append a custom class to a specific menu link item in the navigation bar?

I want the menu links and logo to look like this:

" - - - [ ] - - - "

"-" = menu link

"[]" = menu link transformed into logo

When I auto-center the logo within the theme customizer, the links are only placed on the left side. If there is an easier way you think I could have three links on each side of the centered logo, I'm open to hearing your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Find the place where your navigation menu items list is rendered and add a condition based on menu item title to add a class.

Comment: Post the existing liquid loop